# Storing old data in a list

Tags: c#, .net

I've a method which gets some data (from a transmussion) and the method is called many times. I want to use data of the last transmission in this method. But

```
private List<byte> _dataOfLastMsg = new List<byte>();

internal List<msg> GetData (Imsgod msgod, List<Byte> data)
{
    if (data == null || data.Count == 0)
            return transmission;

    // Call x
    // USING _dataOfLastMsg

    ...
    ...

    if (data.Count != 0)
        _dataOfLastMsg = data;

}
```

Example:

- Msg 1: 0 0 70 0 0
- Msg 2: 0 0 0 0 0
- Msg 3: 20 0 0 0 20

  - Call 1 of GetData: _dataOfLastMsg = 0 0 70 0 0
  - Call 2 of GetData: _dataOfLastMsg = 0 0 70 0 0
  - Call 3 of GetData: _dataOfLastMsg = 20 0 0 0 20

At call 3 the _dataOfLastMsg should be 0 0 70 0 0, because the call of _dataOfLastMsg is before this line: `_dataOfLastMsg = data`;

Whats wrong? Sorry for my bad english

Comment: the function of your code will not compile as it as no return value defined... is difficult to answer a question about the result of a function that has not return defined :)

Answer (score 0):

About 90% of the code required to give you a sensible answer to this is missing, but here's something to think about.

Where are you calling this class?
Is an instance kept or is it recreated every time?
What is the actual output data and how are you calling it?
What is transmission and why are you returning it when data is empty?
What does //Call x mean?
Which data are you feeding into the program and how?

From what I can vaguely tell, on your third call your transmission is returned instead of _dataOfLastMsg, but the only way to tell is to slap down a breakpoint at the start of the method and hit debug to see the logical paths taken in your program and how the variables change.